# What is the C# Syntax for something like date.IsWithIn(x months).Of(Comparison Date)?

Tags: c#, datetime, lambda, extension-methods

The title is a bit whacky, but that's the question. I'm using C#. I'm trying to come up with several DateTime extension methods. While thinking about it, I wondered what syntax it would take for me to write the code as follows:

```
DateTime comparisonDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);

if( DateTime.Now.IsWithIn(3).Of(comparisonDate) ) ....
```

I've written extension methods before, but I'm not sure how composing something like this would work. The "IsWithIn" would be one method...but would this return an Expression and the "Of" method would be an extension method of the Expression class?

**EDIT 1**

Still thinking about this. I'm wondering if this approach, though readable, is over complicating things. My first revision just tweaks @Wai Ha Lee's is to the DateTimeExtensions class. I'll refactor this and keep iterating. This screams strategy pattern but I haven't fit that into it yet. There's also no "Of" method now and the method name seems to make sense...today at least. A month from now? I'm not sure.

I also thought of another way I'd like to be able to write this code. I guess I'm still dreaming, but here that goes:

```
date.IsWithIn(1).Days().Of(comparisonDate);
date.IsWithIn(1).Months().Of(comparisonDate);
date.IsWithIn(1).Years().Of(comparisonDate);
```

But that aside, here's the revision I have that's merely a DateTime extension without the method name chaining.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime past = new DateTime(2015, 1, 15);
        DateTime future = new DateTime(2015, 3, 15);
        DateTime comparison = now.AddDays(-2);
        int interval = 1;
        DateInterval di = DateInterval.Days;

        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Format("Now, {0}, is with in {1} {2} of {3} is {4}",
                now.ToShortDateString(),
                interval.ToString(),
                di.ToString(),
                comparison.ToShortDateString(),
                now.IsDateWithinXRangeOfAnotherDate(interval, di, comparison).ToString())
        );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

  public enum DateInterval
    {
        Days,
        Months,
        Years
    }

public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDateWithinXRangeOfAnotherDate(this DateTime date, int interval, DateInterval dateInterval, DateTime comparisonDate)
    {
        DateTime _min = comparisonDate;
        DateTime _max = comparisonDate;

        switch(dateInterval)
        {
            case DateInterval.Days:
                _min = _min.AddDays(-interval);
                _max = _max.AddDays(interval); 
                Console.WriteLine(
                    string.Format("Min Date is {0} Max Date is {1}",
                        _min.ToShortDateString(),
                        _max.ToShortDateString()));
                break;
            case DateInterval.Months:
                _min = _min.AddMonths(-interval);
                _max = _max.AddMonths(interval);
                Console.WriteLine(
                    string.Format("Min Date is {0} Max Date is {1}",
                        _min.ToShortDateString(),
                        _max.ToShortDateString()));
                break;
            case DateInterval.Years:
                _min = _min.AddYears(-interval);
                _max = _max.AddYears(interval);
                Console.WriteLine(
                    string.Format("Min Date is {0} Max Date is {1}",
                        _min.ToShortDateString(),
                        _max.ToShortDateString()));
                break;
        }

        return _min <= date && date <= _max;
    }        
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Revising:

```
date.IsWithIn(1).Days().Of(comparisonDate);
date.IsWithIn(1).Months().Of(comparisonDate);
date.IsWithIn(1).Years().Of(comparisonDate);
```

to

```
date.IsWithIn(1.Days()).Of(comparisonDate);
date.IsWithIn(1.Months()).Of(comparisonDate);
date.IsWithIn(1.Years()).Of(comparisonDate);
```

After looking at FluentTime for a bit, I noticed the author used several methods and classes I didn't even know existed. For one, he used the TimeSpan.FromDays method. He may have overloaded the + symbol because, at another point in the code, he just adds the timespan to a date. Given how TimeSpans work, I may only be able to implement the 1.Days() portion...and I think that's all I really need.

Will keep playing around with all this until I get it figured out. I could just use the FluentTime library, but it's overkill for what I need this for as the library handles time as well. I'm strictly interested in date range comparisons. Methods like After(), Before(), IsBetween(), IsWithIn. I've implemented the first 3 already. This question pivots on answering the last one.

**EDIT 3 - SOLVED!**

This question has become more an exercise in code than practicality. Ultimately, Jon Skeet was right about having to create a custom type. The solution breaks down to this summary:

A custom class: FluentDateTime was created
3 int Extension methods - Days, Months, Years. These each return a FluentDateTime class.
1 DateTime extension method - IsWithIn that takes a FluentDateTime parameter

I want to emphasize that this is a lot of buck for very little bang...but, regardless, here's the code.

```
public class FluentDateTime
    {

        public enum DateInterval
        {
            Days,
            Months,
            Years
        }

        private DateTime _lowDate;
        private DateTime _highDate;
        public DateTime BaseDate { get; set; }
        public DateInterval Interval { get; set; }
        public int Increment { get; set; }


        public bool Of(DateTime dt)
        {
            _lowDate = dt;
            _highDate = dt;

            if(this.Interval == DateInterval.Days)
            {
                _lowDate = _lowDate.AddDays(-this.Increment);
                _highDate = _highDate.AddDays(this.Increment);
            }
            else if (this.Interval == DateInterval.Months)
            {
                _lowDate = _lowDate.AddMonths(-this.Increment);
                _highDate = _highDate.AddMonths(this.Increment);
            }
            else
            {
                _lowDate = _lowDate.AddYears(-this.Increment);
                _highDate = _highDate.AddYears(this.Increment);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("{0} <= {1} <= {2}", _lowDate.ToShortDateString(), BaseDate.ToShortDateString(), _highDate.ToShortDateString()
                ));

            return (_lowDate < BaseDate && BaseDate < _highDate) || (_lowDate.Equals(BaseDate) || _highDate.Equals(BaseDate) );            
        }

    }
```

// DATETIME EXTENSION

```
public static FluentDateTime IsWithIn(this DateTime date, FluentDateTime fdtParams)
{
    fdtParams.BaseDate = date;
    return fdtParams;
}
```

//INT EXTENSIONS

```
 public static FluentDateTime Days(this int inc)
        {
            FluentDateTime fdt = new FluentDateTime();
            fdt.Interval = FluentDateTime.DateInterval.Days;
            fdt.Increment = inc;
            return fdt;
        }

        public static FluentDateTime Months(this int inc)
        {
            FluentDateTime fdt = new FluentDateTime();
            fdt.Interval = FluentDateTime.DateInterval.Months;
            fdt.Increment = inc;
            return fdt;
        }

        public static FluentDateTime Years(this int inc)
        {
            FluentDateTime fdt = new FluentDateTime();
            fdt.Interval = FluentDateTime.DateInterval.Years;
            fdt.Increment = inc;
            return fdt;
        }
```

//TEST PROGRAM

```
DateTime testDate1 = new DateTime(2015, 3, 3);
            DateTime testDate2 = new DateTime(2015, 3, 4);
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("{0} is within 5 days of {1}? {2} (should be true)",
                    testDate1.ToShortDateString(), testDate2.ToShortDateString(), testDate1.IsWithIn(5.Days()).Of(testDate2)
                ));

            testDate1 = new DateTime(2015, 3, 1);
            testDate2 = new DateTime(2015, 3, 7);
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("{0} is within 3 days of {1}? {2} (should be false)",
                    testDate1.ToShortDateString(), testDate2.ToShortDateString(), testDate1.IsWithIn(3.Days()).Of(testDate2)
                ));

            testDate1 = new DateTime(2015, 3, 3);
            testDate2 = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(
                 string.Format("{0} is within 1 month of {1}? {2} (should be true)",
                     testDate1.ToShortDateString(), testDate2.ToShortDateString(), testDate1.IsWithIn(1.Months()).Of(testDate2)
                 ));


            testDate1 = new DateTime(2015, 3, 3);
            testDate2 = new DateTime(2015, 6, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("{0} is within 2 month of {1}? {2} (should be false)",
                    testDate1.ToShortDateString(), testDate2.ToShortDateString(), testDate1.IsWithIn(2.Months()).Of(testDate2)
                ));
```

Comment: Yes, you return your custom type that has the continued methods.

Comment: You can check existing framework as example - https://github.com/duelinmarkers/FluentTime

Comment: How about an extension method to generate `TimeSpan` on the fly so you can type `3.Months()` and have `IsWithin` accept a time span as parameter instead?

Comment: @mbx I think that's a sensible idea, although I suppose you still have the unhappy property that date.IsWithin(3.Months()) is a valid expression with a nonsensical result (until you add the Of part, I mean to say).

Comment: @emodendroket I agree. `IsWhatever(arg)` should return a boolean. I'd prefer generating the interval, then checking with `myInterval.IsWithin(pointInTime)` on my interval type. Using NodaTime would probably be the better option if you haven't already an implementation of the key concepts.

Comment: In [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28776112/1364007) I added `struct DateTimeRange`, and `static class DateTimeExtensions` which contained an `IsWithin(...)` extension method taking a DateTime and seven optional parameters: { milliseconds, ..., years }. This is the approach that @chris suggests.

Comment: @mbx - as @emodendroket and @ScottChamberlain points out, 3 months is undefined without a reference point. My approach calculates a range based on a reference point so that `x` months is well defined.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov, thanks for that suggestion. It does almost exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trolling the code now. It has me in loops atm. Great reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsWithin` would have to return some sort of type representing a range of values, remembering the "centre" and the range size. Now `Of` could be an extension method of that, or could easily be a normal instance method, given that you'd be writing the type yourself.

Note that `3` isn't clear in terms of being 3 days, 3 hours or something else. You should work out how you want to specify that. You could take a `TimeSpan` instead of just an `int`, or have separate `IsWithinDays`, `IsWithinHours` etc methods.

Comment: I didn't do it. Kind of geeking out Skeet jumped on this so quickly.

Comment: @jason: It's a mixture of a C# language question and a date/time question - what's not to like? :) On the other hand, I'm mock-hurt that you're doing it on DateTime instead of using Noda Time...

Answer (score 2):

**A few things:**

- I assume that **within `{some time}` of** means `{some time}` *either side of* - if it just refers to after, the code is much simpler. Keeping my assumption means that `.IsWithin(x).Of` is commutative, i.e. `a.IsWithin(x).Of(b) == b.IsWithin(x).Of(a)`.
- `DateTimeRange` takes a `Func<DateTime, int, DateTime>` to avoid duplicated code (though there'd not be a range for that if my assumption a
- I don't use TimeSpan [because](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan)

> The largest unit of time that the TimeSpan structure uses to measure duration is a day.
>
> Without hyperbole, this is the **worst thing ever**, and I hate myself a little for posting this. I would *never* write code like this in a professional context. I've only done this to (almost) satisfy @jason's requirements (I renamed `IsWithIn` to `IsWithin`).
>
> **Usage**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var comparisonDate = now.AddMonths(-2);

    bool within1Month = now.IsWithin(months: 1).Of(comparisonDate); // false
    bool within2Months = now.IsWithin(months: 2).Of(comparisonDate); // true
    bool within3Months = now.IsWithin(months: 3).Of(comparisonDate); // true
}
```

**DateTimeExtensions:**

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Specify exactly one of milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, or years.</para>
    /// <para>Uses the first nonzero argument in the order specified.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTimeRange IsWithin(
        this DateTime dateTime,
        int milliseconds = 0, int seconds = 0, int minutes = 0, int hours = 0,
        int days = 0, int months = 0, int years = 0)
    {
        if ( milliseconds != 0 )
            return new DateTimeRange(dateTime, (_dateTime, _value) => _dateTime.AddMilliseconds(_value), milliseconds);
        if ( seconds != 0 )
            return new DateTimeRange(dateTime, (_dateTime, _value) => _dateTime.AddSeconds(_value), seconds);
        if ( minutes != 0 )
            return new DateTimeRange(dateTime, (_dateTime, _value) => _dateTime.AddMinutes(_value), minutes);
        if ( hours != 0 )
            return new DateTimeRange(dateTime, (_dateTime, _value) => _dateTime.AddHours(_value), hours);
        if ( days != 0 )
            return new DateTimeRange(dateTime, (_dateTime, _value) => _dateTime.AddDays(_value), days);
        if ( months != 0 )
            return new DateTimeRange(dateTime, (_dateTime, _value) => _dateTime.AddMonths(_value), months);
        if ( years != 0 )
            return new DateTimeRange(dateTime, (_dateTime, _value) => _dateTime.AddYears(_value), years);

        throw new ArgumentException("At least one value must be nonzero");
    }
}
```

**DateTimeRange:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a range between two DateTime values
/// </summary>
public struct DateTimeRange
{
    private DateTime _min;
    private DateTime _max;

    public DateTime Min { get { return _min; } }
    public DateTime Max { get { return _max; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses generator to get the start and end dates of this range.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="middle">The midpoint of this DateTimeRange</param>
    /// <param name="generator">Generates the min and max dates from the midpoint and a parameter</param>
    public DateTimeRange(DateTime middle, Func<DateTime, int, DateTime> generator, int value)
    {
        _min = generator(middle, -value);
        _max = generator(middle, +value);
    }

    public bool Of(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return _min <= dateTime && dateTime <= _max;
    }
}
```

---

*<sup>I feel a little ashamed to post this as the only other answer to a question @jonskeet has answered.</sup>*

Comment: The reason the largest unit of measure a TimeSpan can do is a Day is you can't say how big a month is unless you know what month you are in. Otherwise you would have to have a `static TimeSpan TimeSpan.FromMonths(double months, int startingMonth, int startingYear)` method signature to reliably figure out how many seconds are in 13 months.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I figured - a 1 month `TimeSpan` is poorly defined without a reference point (e.g. 1 month (forwards) from today (February 27th) is 28 days; 1 month (backwards) from today is 31 days, etc.).

Comment: @WaiHaLee thanks for posting this. In my opinion, the only issue with this code is the DateTimeExtensions method, which you pointed out. I'm going to make an edit to the question that might give us some other ideas.

Comment: @jason - I definitely agree with that. I couldn't think of a better way of a nice way of getting the user to specify the type of number they are passing in. I did consider adding `enum TimeIntervalType { Milliseconds, Seconds, ... Months, Years }` but then you're still left with having to get **from** the enum to modifying a `DateTime` (unless you use reflection to get the method in `DateTime` then invoke it manually - which would be even worse).